# how to get first and last day of quarter and the cutoff in hive time dimension

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am building a query in hive to create a time dimension which will pick the date from 2010-01-01 to the current date and display year quarter year_cutoff(date -7) and quarter cutoff(date - 7)

Query:

```
    with dates as (
    select date_add("2010-01-01", a.pos) as d from (select posexplode(split(repeat("o", datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), "2010-01-01")), "o"))) a)
    select d as date_today,year(d) as year,CONCAT('Q',(INT((MONTH(d)-1)/3)+1)) AS QUARTER,YEAR(date_add(d, -7)) AS year_cutoff,
    CONCAT('Q',(INT((MONTH(date_add(d, -7))-1)/3)+1)) AS QUARTER_cutoff,trunc(add_months(d,-(month(d)-1)%3),'MM')  as Firstday_quarter
    from dates
```

result:

```
| date_today |    year |  quarter | year_cutoff  | quarter_cutoff |  Firstday_quarter  
----------   |  -----  | ------   | ------------ |  ----------    |  ----------
|2010-01-01  |    2010 |    Q1    |   2009       |   Q4           | 2010-01-01
|2010-01-02  |   2010  |    Q1    |   2009       |   Q4           | 2010-01-01
|2010-01-03  |    2010 |    Q1    |   2009       |   Q4           |   2010-01-01
```

I need to calculate 3 more columns like quarter_last_date,Firstday_quartercutoff,last_date_quarter_cutoff,
out of which I figured out the firstday_quarter Could you please let me know how i can fetch the rest 3 columns using hive

Ex:

| date_today | Firstday_quarter | Lastday_quarter | Firstday_quartercutoff | Lastday_quartercutoff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-07 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-31 | 2009-10-01 | 2009-12-31 |

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will solve your questions.

1. First date of the quarter: `select trunc('2010-01-02','Q') from schema.table`
2. Last date of the quarter: `select date_sub(add_months(trunc('2010-01-02', 'Q'), 3), 1) from schema.table`

Result

```
first_day_of_the_quarter|last_day_of_the_quarter
      2010-01-01        |       2010-03-31
```